# Buy signals for pine script strategy to 3Commas

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am learning Pine Script (albeit very slowly). I have a borrowed script for a strategy that I would like to create an alert so that I can send the buy and close signals to a 3Commas bot. The closest help I have found so far is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d_rFRd3o-0&t=1292s however, the script I am trying it with has more than one entry and exit. Any ideas? Script as follows:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © AliNotty

// with thanks to MarketShree 

//@version=5
strategy('Supertrend Strategy', overlay=true)

atrPeriod1 = input(7, 'ATR Length-1')
factor1 = input(1.5, 'Factor-1')
atrPeriod2 = input(10, 'ATR Length-2')
factor2 = input(2, 'Factor-2')
atrPeriod3 = input(20, 'ATR Length-3')
factor3 = input(3, 'Factor-3')

[superTrend1, direction1] = ta.supertrend(factor1, atrPeriod1)
[superTrend2, direction2] = ta.supertrend(factor2, atrPeriod2)
[superTrend3, direction3] = ta.supertrend(factor3, atrPeriod3)

if ta.change(direction1) < 0
    strategy.entry('LONG', strategy.long)

if ta.change(direction1) > 0
    strategy.entry('SHORT', strategy.short)

if ta.change(direction2) < 0
    strategy.entry('LONG', strategy.long)

if ta.change(direction2) > 0
    strategy.entry('SHORT', strategy.short)

if ta.change(direction3) < 0
    strategy.entry('LONG', strategy.long)

if ta.change(direction3) > 0
    strategy.entry('SHORT', strategy.short)

colResistance = direction1 == 1 and direction1 == direction1[1] ? color.new(color.red, 0) : color.new(color.red, 100)
colSupport = direction1 == -1 and direction1 == direction1[1] ? color.new(color.green, 0) : color.new(color.green, 100)
plot(superTrend1, color=colResistance, linewidth=2)
plot(superTrend1, color=colSupport, linewidth=2)

colResistance1 = direction2 == 1 and direction2 == direction2[1] ? color.new(color.red, 0) : color.new(color.red, 100)
colSupport1 = direction2 == -1 and direction2 == direction2[1] ? color.new(color.green, 0) : color.new(color.green, 100)
plot(superTrend2, color=colResistance, linewidth=2)
plot(superTrend2, color=colSupport, linewidth=2)

colResistance2 = direction3 == 1 and direction3 == direction3[1] ? color.new(color.red, 0) : color.new(color.red, 100)
colSupport2 = direction3 == -1 and direction3 == direction3[1] ? color.new(color.green, 0) : color.new(color.green, 100)
plot(superTrend3, color=colResistance1, linewidth=2)
plot(superTrend3, color=colSupport1, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script uses 3 supertrend
Maybe you only need one of those 3 for your 3 commas long/short bots no?
Don't forget to edit the alert_message paramters from the strategy.entry function :)

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © AliNotty

// with thanks to MarketShree 

//@version=5
strategy('Supertrend Strategy', overlay=true)

atrPeriod1 = input(7, 'ATR Length-1')
factor1 = input(1.5, 'Factor-1')


[superTrend1, direction1] = ta.supertrend(factor1, atrPeriod1)

if ta.change(direction1) < 0
    strategy.entry('LONG', strategy.long, alert_message = "3 commas open long deal command")

if ta.change(direction1) > 0
    strategy.entry('SHORT', strategy.short, alert_message = "3 commas open short deal command")

colResistance = direction1 == 1 and direction1 == direction1[1] ? color.new(color.red, 0) : color.new(color.red, 100)
colSupport = direction1 == -1 and direction1 == direction1[1] ? color.new(color.green, 0) : color.new(color.green, 100)
plot(superTrend1, color=colResistance, linewidth=2)
plot(superTrend1, color=colSupport, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thank you Daveatt! I didn't realise the strategy was firing up to 3 deals at a time and thought it was using a combination of the 3 supertrends. I played with the inputs and managed to get 400% on 15m for BTCUP (inputs 5,7,10,6,8,7 if interested). I assume if I wanted to run this, I would need to set up 3 bots (although I would need to see if all three were profitable first). Does the strategy buy on the long entry and sell on the short entry?

Comment: Does the strategy buy on the long entry and sell on the short entry? 
Correct for a spot asset
For a derivatives assets, a long entry is treated as a long entry, and a short entry is treated as a short

Comment: Thank you. I separated the 3 directions out (which we’re giving approx 400% on 15m BTCUP, and tried each one separately and didn’t get anywhere near 400% if I added the results together. Bizarre. Thanks again.